# pointers don't change after i modified it

Tags: c, pointers, scope

I'm setting up a struct called Node

```
    typedef struct node{
struct node *left;
struct node *right;
struct node *parent;
    }node;
```

and a function that operate on the nodes:

```
   int test(node *old,node* new){
old->parent->right = new;
new->parent = old->parent;
    }
```

Ok, so i make 3 nodes and set up the relationship between them

```
node* me =malloc(sizeof(node));
node* me1 = malloc(sizeof(node));
node* me2 = malloc(sizeof(node));
me->right = me1;
me->left = me2;
me1->parent = me;
me2->parent = me;
test(me1,me);
```

1.However, after test(), me1->parent->right changed while  me1 didn't, which is weird because me1 and me1->parent->right point are the same address. I wonder if i make any wrong assumption here?

2.In function test(), if i replace old->parent->right with old only, then after the function call, the node me1 remains the same. Isn't the pointer modified after we do operations on it inside a function,and why in this case it is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`me`, `me1`, and `me2` are local variables inside your outer function (let's assume it was `main`). These pointers are never modified, so after the call to `test`, `me1` still points to the same node as before, while the pointer `me1->parent->right` now points to `me`. So, "me1 and me1->parent->right point are the same address" isn't true anymore!

If you only modify `old` inside `test`, you will only modify the parameter `old`, which is a copy of `me1`. After `test` returns, this copy is forgotten, and the modification has no effect. If you want to modify the `me1` variable from within `test`, you will have to pass a pointer to the pointer, i.e. a double pointer:

```c
int test(node **old,node* new){
  *old = new;
  ...
}
```

and call it as `test(&me1,me);`.

Also: Please don't name things "new", because if you ever decide to compile the code as C++, this will conflict with the reserved keyword `new`.

Comment: Wait, after test() , me1->parent->right points to me, but isn't me1->parent->right the same as me1? So consequently, should me1 also point to me? Isn't me1->parent->right and me1 the same object?

Comment: "Isn't me1->parent->right and me1 the same object" - No! They are two distinct pointer variables, that after the `me->right = me1;` assignment just happen to point to the same `node`, i.e. the one initially assigned to `me1`. After the `old->parent->right = new` assignment, `me->right` now points to `me`, but `me1` still points to the same thing. Nowhere in your code is there a `me1 = something` assignment, so `me1` always points to the same thing. I think you have a basic misunderstanding how pointers work, maybe read the appropriate chapters in a good C book...

Answer (score 0):

Here is what your `test()` method does:

```
int test(node *old,node* new){
    old->parent->right = new;
    new->parent = old->parent;
}
```

when you call this:

```
me->right = me1;
me1->parent = me;
test(me1,me);
```

These steps happens:

1. `me1`'s `parent` is `me` and `me`'s `right` is `me1`. So `me`'s right becomes `me` again.
2. `me`'s `parent` becomes `me` itself.